# ggplot2: multiple legend as table

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to show multiple legend as table. For example,

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:4, 4), 
  y = c(1:4, 2:5, 3:6, 4:7), 
  a = rep(rep(c("a1", "a2"), each=4), 2), 
  b = rep(c("b1", "b2"), each=8))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=b, shape=a)) + 
  geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~ b)
```

I can get multiple legend with different colours and different shape. But I want to show my legend such as

```
     b1 | b2
--------------
a1 | o  |  o
a2 | ^  |  ^
```

How can I draw legend like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example:

```
p <- ggplotGrob(ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=b, shape=a)) + 
  geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~ b) + theme(legend.position = "none"))

leg <- ggplotGrob(ggplot(unique(subset(dat, select = a:b)), aes(a, b, colour=b, shape=a)) + geom_point() +
   coord_equal() +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()))

library(gtable)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(vp = viewport(width = 0.8, x = 0.4))
grid.draw(p)
popViewport()
pushViewport(vp = viewport(width = 0.2, x = 1-0.1))
grid.draw(leg)
popViewport()
```

[image]

And you can tweak the appearance by customizing the `theme`.

Comment: you could flip a and b, and use facet titles to have the labels above the legend.

Comment: also, this is crazy. in a good way. You should write a `legendary` package.